# How do I reuse Bloodhound prefetched json file?

Tags: javascript, json, bloodhound

I have this piece of code in my page :

```
var dataSourceUniques = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('uniqueName', 
       'baseItem'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: "uniques.json",
        cache: false
    }
});
```

How can I access keys and values in the prefetched json file without requesting it again? Like this:

```
function getValue() {
     return dataSourceUniques['key']['value']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working! I used the transform function and assigned the response to a globally available object.

```
var objects = {};

var dataSourceUniques = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('uniqueName', 'baseItem'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: {
        url: "uniques.json",
        cache: false,
        transform: function(response) {
            objects.uniquesObject = response;
            return response;
        }
    }
});
```

Now I can do `objects.uniquesObject['key']`